# How to hide Chatter Settings

Tags: chatter

I wanted to know how can we restrict access to "chatter settings".
Under Setup > App Setup> Chatter so that its not accidentally enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Only users with "Customize Application" will be able to Enable / Disable Chatter.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_setting_up.htm&language=en_US